# How are functions and variables attached to php files in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently getting a massive head ache trying to figure out how Wordpress scope works. I'm new to php and scripting languages in general. Right now I have an email template file open and I can see variables and functions all over the place. Yet I don't see these variables or functions defined anywhere. This file isn't a class so it's not like these functions and variables are being inherited from anywhere. So where are they coming from?

Example:

`do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email );`

I know what this function does and I know what these variables are, but where are they defined? And how did these definitions get attached to this file?

I've been trying to figure this out forever but I'm stuck.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend finding a good book or online class for Wordpress development.  There is a method and structure to it which involves massive global variables, and it is generally difficult to dive into without some guidance, especially if you are new to PHP and scripting languages as well

Comment: What would the topic that I need to study up on be called?

Comment: Udemy has a lot of great wordpress theming classes and studying PHP is a must, especially if you are coming from the application world.  Good luck!